# Separating data on a table based on data on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables like below:

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

I want to be able to categorize product pounds data on table 2 based on the product type on table 1. How is this done in SQL?

Comment: What does "categorize product pounds data" mean?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the date column for join and sum the value for each date

```
select a.productType, b.Date, sum(b.ProductPounds)
from table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.date = b.date
group by a.productType, b.date
```

or if you don't need  the sum but just a relation then

```
select a.productType, b.Date, b.ProductPounds
from table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on a.date = b.date
```

Comment: Is there a way to separate them out without summing the productType?